# Отправка данных с формы через PHPMailer

Tags: php, form, email, smtp, phpmailer

У меня есть след. код для отправки данных с формы на почту через PHPMailer:

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

$mail->isSMTP();  
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                         
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.titan.email';                     
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
$mail->Username   = 'EMAIL';                     
$mail->Password   = 'PASSWORD';                               
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'SSL/TLS ';     
$mail->Port       = 465;                                  

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('EMAIL', 'Mailtrap');
    $mail->addAddress('EMAIL');

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    $mail->Body = "Application was submitted from the site \r\n" . "Name: " . $name . "\r\n" . "Email: " . $email . "\r\n" . "Phone: " . $phone . "\r\n" . "Text: " . $text;

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'The email message was sent.';
    }
?>
```

Хостинг: hostinger
Этот код был взят с их сайта (https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/send-emails-using-php-mail)

Но при отправке идет бесконечная загрузка.

Пытался вывести данные через echo, убрав `$mail->send()`, все работало и данные выводились, но когда добавляю функцию send() идет бесконечная загрузка.

Comment: Попробуйте задебажить сам $mail->send()

Comment: Задам очень странный вопрос, но как это делается? я просто в php незарбираюсь, фронтом только занимаюсь. Вроде и в настройках хостинка тоже такого нету

Comment: Если у вас, как вы говорить просто echo работают, а вызов метода send объекта $mail стопорит работу скрипта, значит проблема либо в методе либо в объекте)

Comment: найдите документацию на hostinger про этот объект и гляньте как оно должно работать, кроме того попробуйте выполнить перед началом ```if()``` просмотра! ```var_dump($mail); exit;```